# What is the word that both of them are talking about?

Tags: word, story

Context: Both Max and his friend Lisa have been told a word by their teacher and their conversation goes as follows:

> Max: "What was the word that teacher told us again?" 
>   Lisa: "What? Why weren't you listening?" 
>   Max: "I hate the teacher, so I was zoning out" 
>   Lisa: "Why? Even though you don't like the teacher, listening to her is a rule of conduct!" 
>   Max: "Why are you talking to me about an expression for a general truth or principal?" 
>   Lisa: "Because it is your name, and you should live up to it!" 
>   Max: "Never mind, I'd better ask my mum about this word" 
>   Lisa: "Um..."

After this conversation, Max immediately knew exactly what word the teacher had said. What word was it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Is it

> MAXIMUM?

Because

> "a general truth or principal" = MAXIM, plus Lisa's last word "Um" is MAXIMUM.

And

> "it is your name, and you should live up to it" - contains MAX - plus "I'd better ask my mum about this word" - contains MUM.

Maybe there are also further clues towards this word that I didn't spot.

Comment: Wow, that was fast! Great job :)

Comment: @UnidentifiedX Thanks for the [inspiration](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/94165/5373) :-)