# Max and Lisa are arguing again

Tags: word, story

Shortly after [this conversation](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/94162/5373), Max and Lisa had another argument:

> Max: Huh? What's going on?
>   Lisa: You're browsing the web with your smartphone instead of paying attention!
>   Max: I was sending a message to my sister!
>   Lisa: Oh, is she picking you up in her car after school?
>   Max: Yes, we're going to play music together.
>   Lisa: You should listen to the teacher, she's showing us the lower-case Greek alphabet.
>   Max: I care less about that than anything else!

What word did he miss this time?

<sub>This puzzle is inspired by [the previous one](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/94162/5373), but it can be solved independently.</sub>

Comment: Is is ok for me to solve it?

Comment: @UnidentifiedX Sure. The style is similar to yours, but the clues fit together in a different way. I don't think you have any unfair advantage here.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think the word is

> Minimum

Thanks to Darrel Hoffman for pointing out that

> The nth line clues the first n letters of the word.

Huh? What's going on?

> Huh? Could be synonymous for **M?** (hmmm?)

You're browsing the web with your smartphone instead of paying attention!

> **Mi** - perhaps referring to the [Xiaomi Mi MIX Alpha](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xiaomi_Mi_MIX_Alpha)

I was sending a message to my sister!

> Perhaps Max's sister's name is **Min** (short for Minimum)

Oh, is she picking you up in her car after school?

> A **Mini** Cooper

Yes, we're going to play music together.

> With lots of **minim**s.

You should listen to the teacher, she's showing us the lower-case Greek alphabet.

> Perhaps, in particular, a **mini mu**

I care less about that than anything else!

> He cares the **minimum** amount.

Comment: That's correct. The first and second lines also have meaning cluing something specific (although it was a little harder to clue in those cases).

Comment: Ah, okay, I will think on it.

Comment: @hexomino Nice work!  Could it be possible that Max is rot13(oebjfvat jvgu Bcren Zvav)?

Comment: @hagfy Ah, yes, nice. I'll add that in.

Comment: You still haven't quite got how it all fits together. I'll post another comment with a hint maybe in a few hours.

Comment: I believe that you should rot13(fgneg jvgu bar yrggre - "z", naq nqq bar yrggre sbe rnpu pyhr).

Comment: @DarrelHoffman Ah, yes, you must be right.

Answer (score 3):

Is the word:

> Delta?

Because:

> Max doesn't care about learning it, because he thinks he knows what it is already, as a lower case delta symbol looks a bit like a Treble Clef, which he would know if he can play music.

Comment: Nope, sorry. When you find the intended solution, all the clues should fit together in a specific way.

Answer (score 1):

Is the word:

> iota

Because

> Max does not give an iota?

Comment: Nope, sorry. When you find the intended solution, all the clues should fit together in a specific way.

Comment: Yeah I have no idea wtf is going on here.